# Conditional Login redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I saw this code online and would like to modify it such that the user will be redirected to a certain page only if that's their previous page.

Let's assume the page is https://example.com/courses/lear-how-to-code/ , before starting the course a user must sign in. As it stand they are redirected to my-account page after signing in but I would like then to be redirected to https://example.com/courses/lear-how-to-code/.

The code should work like that only if https://example.com/courses/lear-how-to-code/ is the previous page before the woocommerce login page.

Please see code below:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect'); 

function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {

   $redirect_to = 'PUT HERE URL OF THE PAGE';
   return $redirect_to;

}
```

I am new to PHP and WordPress and really need help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it right. just use WP [home_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/) function and pass or append the your URL to that function. in your case check the below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file. this code tested and works.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'redirect_user_to_specific_page_after_login');
function redirect_user_to_specific_page_after_login( $redirect_to ) {
    $redirect_to = home_url( '/courses/lear-how-to-code/' ); 
    return $redirect_to;
}
```